# Product does not appear in product list

Tags: product, ce-1.7.0.2

let me know what could happen? on the frontend I do not see half of the products and Product does not appear in product list, how could this happen? No products that I added in the last 2 weeks, but I can see the admin panel products, and products enabled by categories are - no errors

What to do?
Thanks

Comment: http://bit.ly/1yNxG4v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have not marked the product as out of stock (out of stock products will not appear in the product page).